# VBA Addod: take non empty value form the cell

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I would like to take the value from C6 for my sql query. But, I would like to do it in case if C6 is not empty. I don't know how translate this option in my code. My code is :

```
Public Sub INFO_PROTO34(ByRef strQ As String)

Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset
RECSET.Open "select proto.b_perf_cma as b_perf_cma, proto.b_perf_supp_ann as b_perf_supp_ann, proto.b_perf_ctrat_gar as b_perf_ctrat_gar from db_dossier sousc,db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
            " where sousc.no_police = Range("C6") and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit and '" & strQ & "' = proto.is_protocole ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
If Not RECSET.EOF Then
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient").Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_ctrat_gar").Value
Else
   
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient").Value = "0"
End If
RECSET.Close
End Sub
```

Thank you very much for you suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```vb
Public Sub INFO_PROTO34(ByRef strQ As String)

    Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset, v
    
    v = Range("C6").Value 'Activesheet?  Really need a specific worksheet here
    
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        RECSET.Open " select proto.b_perf_cma as b_perf_cma, proto.b_perf_supp_ann as b_perf_supp_ann, " & _
            " proto.b_perf_ctrat_gar as b_perf_ctrat_gar from db_dossier sousc,db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
            " where sousc.no_police = " & v & " and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and " & _
            " sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit" & _
            " and '" & strQ & "' = proto.is_protocole ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
        
        With Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient")
            If Not RECSET.EOF Then
                .Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_ctrat_gar").Value
            Else
                .Value = "0"
            End If
        End With
        RECSET.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

If `sousc.no_police` is not numeric then add single-quotes around the value.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `RECSET.OPEN` you can try using the `IsEmpty` method

I didn't test this out on VBA script yet but here's how I'd change your code to take C6 cell into account depending if its blank or not:

```
Public Sub INFO_PROTO34(ByRef strQ As String)

Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset

 if IsEmpty(Range("C6").value) = true then 
   ' if C6 cell is blank or empty it will do the SQL without the C6 cell value
   RECSET.Open "select proto.b_perf_cma as b_perf_cma, proto.b_perf_supp_ann as b_perf_supp_ann, proto.b_perf_ctrat_gar as b_perf_ctrat_gar from db_dossier sousc,db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
            " where sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit and '" & strQ & "' = proto.is_protocole ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

 Else

    ' in this case the cell C6 is not empty/blank so it will use your existing SQL statement
    RECSET.Open "select proto.b_perf_cma as b_perf_cma, proto.b_perf_supp_ann as b_perf_supp_ann, proto.b_perf_ctrat_gar as b_perf_ctrat_gar from db_dossier sousc,db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
            " where sousc.no_police = Range("C6") and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit and '" & strQ & "' = proto.is_protocole ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
 end if

If Not RECSET.EOF Then
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient").Value = RECSET.Fields("b_perf_ctrat_gar").Value
Else
   
    Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient").Value = "0"
End If
RECSET.Close
End Sub
```

See https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isempty.php for more information on the `IsEmpty` method.